# overwrite default behavior of JB4A SDK using EventBus

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

I'm currently trying to send a Cloudpage push message to an App using the JB4A SDK.

I want to bypass the default behavior that sends the Cloudpage to the inbox first prior to displaying it.

My use case would be :

Event triggered by JB > Cloudpage "Send Push" activity fired > Cloudpage displayed automatically in the App.

I was thinking of using the [EventBus](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/eventbus.html) "CloudPagesChangedEvent" event to bypass the inbox and display the cloudpage automatically and I am wondering if some you guys implemeted this for one of your clients ?

Thank you so much for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do might be possible, but there would be no way to block the default behavior of CloudPages.  Have you considered using [OpenDirect](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/opendirect.html) if you do not need the inbox?

Also, 2 things:

1. You can't get to the CloudPage data from the event you're mentioning.
2. The EventBus may not be around for many more releases of the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand well, OpenDirect is basically an Outbound + A custom url that will be embeded in a WebView ?

I don't describe this as an "In App" push because the user will have to click on the outbound push in order to open the Cloudpage in the WebView.. 

What I need is to open the cloud page automatically inside the app.

Comment: Your use case is not currently supported.  Please contact your account manager for insight into the product roadmap or to request features.

Comment: Thank you Bill for your reply! I will check with my account manager. Have a nice weekend !